# "\\SomeServer\drops"-error while running automated tests in teamproject

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I have made a Coded UI Test with VS2015 and created an environment on a virtual machine.
Then on my local machine i connected to the teamproject in VS2013 and started the test build.
Unfortunately i receive an error "\SomeServer\drops".
When i run the tests on the VM by command line, it's all okay.
Can anybody help?

Here the error protocol:

04:41
Overall Build Process

04:41
Application Deployment Workflow

00:00
Update Build Number

00:00
Get Build Details

00:00
If Build is needed

00:00
Get Build Location And Build Number

00:00
Compute build location needed

00:00
Compute build path

00:00
If user selected stored environment

00:00
Get Lab Environment Uri

00:00
Get Lab Environment

00:00
 If Restore Snapshot

00:00
No Clean Snapshot

00:00
If Virtual Environment

00:00
If deployment or test needed

00:00
Wait For Environment To Be Ready

04:40
If deployment needed

04:40
Do deployment

00:00
Reserve Environment For Deployment

04:40
Deploy Build on Environment

04:40
Deploying Build

04:40
Run Deployment scripts

04:40
Run Deployment Task
Deployment Task Logs for Machine: PC-GUI-Test.prosoft.net
 Folgender Pfad konnte nicht für den Zugriff mithilfe des Lab-Dienstkontos hinzugefügt werden: prosoft\devadmin, \SomeServer\drops. Ursache: Der Netzwerkpfad wurde nicht gefunden.
 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
 Exception Message: Team Foundation Server could not complete the deployment task for machine 'pc-gui-test.prosoft.net', script 'C:\deployment.exe' and arguments ''. (type LabDeploymentProcessException)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.RunDeploymentTask.ExecuteDeploymentTask.RunCommand(AsyncState state)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
   bei System.Action`1.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
   bei Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.RunDeploymentTask.ExecuteDeploymentTask.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
   bei System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

00:00
Release Environment From Deployment

Answer (score 2):

*Translate the error message you got into English:*

*Following path could not be added for access using the lab service account: ProSoft\devadmin, \Some Server\drops. Cause: The network path was not found.*

For this error, there are basically two parts you need to have a check:

Firstly, be sure that the **\Some Server\drops** network path does exist.

Secondly, please take note that during execution of the deployment workflow, the build agent configured via workflow capability accesses the build drop location using the lab service account. So you need to grant read permissions to the lab service account on the build drop location.

Please take a look at this blog for the deails: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lab_management/archive/2010/02/22/what-is-lab-service-account.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The bug resulted by a mistaken property in the build definition.
Thanks a lot for Your answers!